# MapFragment suddenly crashed my previously run OK after updating to kitkat sdk

Tags: google-maps, android-4.4-kitkat, mapfragment

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

My MapFragment suddenly crash my googlemap app. This happen after updating SDK to 4.4. All my Googlemap MapFragment based app crash when I run on all my android devices (note 2/3/nexus7). All the setting for google Mapv2 retain..such as library, API key..manifest permission nothing changes. Suddenly after updating to kitkat SDK all  my googlemap v2 apps went haywire.

lo`12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dudewheresmycar/com.dudewheresmycar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2294)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2348)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5414)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at com.dudewheresmycar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
12-15 14:16:37.751: E/AndroidRuntime(20072):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5369)`

Found the solution..need to insert the following tag into manifest.xml

```
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

In the application tag

Comment: Please add details about how it's crashing, and especially important is the logcat output from around the crash.

Comment: I have a project with Google maps and kitkat as a target without any problem. Have you updated the target in your manifest? Have you done a "clean project" and full rebuild? Sometimes eclipse doesn't update all the files in your bin folder, specially when you use proguard

Comment: The crashing is because of the mapfragment xml in the layout. If I remove that well the app is working ok. but of course useless without the googlemap.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution..need to insert the following tag into manifest.xml

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

In the application tag